# animating setImage, delaying setImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been struggling with this for a couple of weeks now. I have a word game and it compares words, when a letter is in the correct place it turns green. now this all works perfectly fine the only thing is that I want the letters to appear not all on the same time, but with some time between them. I have no idea how to do this and I hoped someone could help me. to make it more clear, here is some code:

```
// RANDOM WORD 
unichar aChar7 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:0];
unichar aChar8 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:1];
unichar aChar9 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:2];
unichar aChar10 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:3];
unichar aChar11 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:4];
unichar aChar12 = [textview.text characterAtIndex:5];
//INPUT
unichar aChar1 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:0];
unichar aChar2 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:1];
unichar aChar3 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:2];
unichar aChar4 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:3];
unichar aChar5 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:4];
unichar aChar6 = [labelsText.text characterAtIndex:5];


if (aChar1 == aChar7){
    [imageview7 setImage:imageview1HG.image];
//(Wait 1 second)
if (aChar2 == aChar8){
    [imageview8 setImage:imageview2HG.image];
///Wait 1 second)
if (aChar3 == aChar9){
    [imageview9 setImage:imageview3HG.image];
//Wait 1 second)
if (aChar4 == aChar10){
    [imageview10 setImage:imageview4HG.image];
//wait 1 second
if (aChar5 == aChar11){
    [imageview11 setImage:imageview5HG.image];
 //wait 1 second
if (aChar6 == aChar12){
    [imageview12 setImage:imageview6HG.image];
```

I hope someone knows and can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dispatch_after()`:

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // code to be executed on the main queue after delay
});
```